# Backbone custom event trigger not being recognised?

Tags: backbone.js

I'm learning Backbone.js for the first time and I'm having an issue trying to get a custom event from triggering (or from the View from recognising when it's been triggered)?

You can see my Collection code here: https://github.com/Integralist/Backbone-Playground/blob/master/Assets/Scripts/App/main.js#L72-86 which when initialized it triggers a custom `collection:init` event.

```
var Contacts = Backbone.Collection.extend({
    model: Contact,

    initialize: function(){
        this.trigger('collection:init');
        this.bind('add', this.model_added, this);
    },

    model_added: function(){
        console.log('A new model has been created so trigger an event for the View to update the <select> menu');
    }
});
```

But later on in my View where I'm listening for that event I can't get the function `populate` to fire: https://github.com/Integralist/Backbone-Playground/blob/master/Assets/Scripts/App/main.js#L90-107

```
var ContactsView = Backbone.View.extend({
    initialize: function(){
        console.log(contacts.models, 'get initial model data and populate the select menu?');
    },

    events: {
        'collection:init': 'populate',
        'change select': 'displaySelected'
    },

    populate: function(){
        console.log('populate the <select> with initial Model data');
    },

    displaySelected: function (event) {
        console.log('get model data and display selected user', event);
    }
});
```

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Hi does the view receive the collection through constructor ? during the initialize method inside view have you subscribed to the event like this `this.collection.on("init",this.populate)`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The events hash in a view is used to bind events *from the DOM* to your view, e.g. events raised by the elements in your rendered view. To listen to events raised by your collection, you will have to set them manually:

```
var ContactsView = Backbone.View.extend({
    initialize: function(){
        contacts.on("collection:init",this.populate,this);
    }
    ...
});
```

Note that you are using a global contacts variable, I would advise to use Backbone mechanisms and pass your collection to the constructor, as you do with the el:

```
var ContactsView = Backbone.View.extend({
    initialize: function(){
        console.log(this.collection.models);
        this.collection.on("collection:init",this.populate,this);
    }
    ...
});

var contacts_view = new ContactsView({
    el: $('#view-contacts'),
    collection:contacts
});
```

As @mu said in the comments, as is, your event won't do anything since you trigger it in the initialize method of the collection, which is automatically called by the constructor of the collection therefore before you can bind anything in the view. See this Fiddle to visualize the call order : http://jsfiddle.net/yRuCN/

Trigger it elsewhere, or, if I read correctly your intent, you  (probably) want to use the built in reset event:

```
var ContactsView = Backbone.View.extend({
    initialize: function(){
        this.collection.on("reset",this.populate,this);
    }
    ...
});
```

See http://jsfiddle.net/yRuCN/1/ for an example with potential uses.

Comment: `this.collection.on("collection:init",this.populate,this);` will still have an problem, no? The collection will always be initialized (and `"collection:init"` triggered) before anything can bind to that event.

Comment: @mu You're completely right, I wasn't sure how to explain that, that's why I added the mention about the reset event. I'll edit my answer and add your comment, somehow:)

Comment: I think you're right about the reset event. And the `model_added` should probably be right on the view as well.

Comment: @nikoshr thanks for the response. Ive updated my repo but it's still not triggering the event within the view. 

Updated code here: https://github.com/Integralist/Backbone-Playground/blob/master/Assets/Scripts/App/main.js#L70-86 

I have an empty <select> menu which I want to populate with data from the Collection. When I create the Collection I pass in two Models to it. So I assumed I'd trigger an event within initialize which my View could listen for. Once the View hears the Collection has data it updates the <select> with data from the Collection. 

My updated View code: http://goo.gl/FUhal

Comment: @Integralist That's what Mu and I were discussing in the previous comments, triggering an event in the initialize method won't get you anywhere, nothing can listen to it because initialize is part of the constructor. Check the first Fiddle I just added to see what happens when you create a collection. The second Fiddle should point you in the direction of potential solutions.

Comment: @Integralist and a last Fiddle to demonstrate a custom event http://jsfiddle.net/yRuCN/2/

Comment: @nikoshr thank you for clarifying and providing a 'custom' event version as well - although this isn't strictly an answer it is enough for me to see what I need to do so thank you :-)